# Docker image two-steps build

Tags: docker, automation, installation

I have a third party PHP application to install in a container. The application is shipped without its dependencies. There is a provided script to automate dependency installation, but it relies on a couple of tools not available in my base image (both general utilities like `unzip` as well as some PHP-specific tools like [composer](https://getcomposer.org/)). Those tools are only required for the dependency installation. There are not required afterward.

A simple solution would be to install the required tools and run the installation script in a `RUN` section of my Dockerfile. But I don't want to clutter the image with software only useful during the image build step.

```
  RUN apt-get update && apt-get install --yqq unzip
  RUN wget https://getcomposer.org/download/1.8.3/composer.phar
  RUN php installer.php
  # I end up polluting my container with unused tools and possible
  # behind the scene changes in some files (`php.ini`, ...)
```

Another solution would be to perform the installation on the host and to `COPY` the application alongside its dependencies into the container. But I want a reproducible build.

```
  COPY app/ ./
  # Not reproducible: I do not control the version of
  # the installed app neither the version of the tools
  # and dependencies
```

---

So, I envision a two-steps process:

1. using a first container to perform the installation;
2. then copying the application alongside its dependencies into another "clean" container.

**But I don't see exactly how to achieve that. Do you have any suggestions?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can use two [build stages](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) in your Dockerfile so you don't end up having unnecessary things inside container.  Anything from first stage is gone until you move it to second stage. Something like:

```
FROM whatever as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
RUN wget https://getcomposer.org/download/1.8.3/composer.phar
RUN php installer.php

FROM whatever as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app ./
```

Comment: This is _exactly_ what I was looking for! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome. You may accept the answer ;)

Comment: Done. I've edited the answer to add a link to the docs.

Comment: accepted the edit :-)